# Not setting to PAP freeradius - daloradius

Tags: mysqli, freeradius

I currently have a server with freeradius version 2.2.8 integrated with daloradius 0.9-9. When I try to connect with any user added in daloradius I get the following error:
[pap] WARNING: Auth-Type already set.  Not setting to PAP
++[pap] returns noop

I wanted to know if you could give me give me about itç

Thanks